# Parameters of projection for SMAP data

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, hdf, nasa

I need to extract geotiff from [SMAP DATA](https://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/SMAP/SPL3SMP_E.001/) ([same without registration](http://dlang.ru/files/example.zip))

I found example of gdal_translate command that do this task:

`gdal_translate -a_ullr -17334194 7356860 17334194 -7356860 -a_srs epsg:3975 -a_nodata -9999 HDF5:"C:\files\SMAP_L3_SM_P_E_20170711_R15060_001.h5"://Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_AM/soil_moisture sm0000.tif`

It's produce geotiff, but it's projection is not correct. There is some gap:

[image]

Here is some info that I found:
EPSG:3975 is the Original EASE Grid, while SMAP data is projected onto EASE Grid2.0 (i.e. EPSG:6933)

`+proj=cea +lat 0=0 +lon 0=0 +lat 1=30 +x 0=0 +y 0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m`"

What is gdal_translate string for setting correct data-projection.

I tried to set `EPSG:6933` in QGIS after reprojection to `EPSG:3975`. Images is shifting to very-very little to more correct position. Something like half-pixel.

Comment: Maybe related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159883/how-to-define-a-projection-for-a-file-with-geo-points. The metadata of your file says `Metadata_Extent_northBoundLatitude=85.044502` , which is reprojected to EASE `7314540.11`. 180° Longitude is `17367530.45`, which makes the raster fit to Natural Earth shapefiles.

Comment: @AndreJ please, show the result string for transformation, I am still getting wrong result.

Comment: `gdal_translate -a_ullr -17367530.45 7314540.11 17367530.45 -7314540.11 -a_srs "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m"   -a_nodata -9999 HDF5:"SMAP_L3_SM_P_E_20170711_R15060_001.h5"://Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_AM/soil_moisture sm-ease2.tif`