# gdal_translate outputs coordinates in metres, but I need degrees

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdal-translate, hdf5

I wish to convert a HDF5 file into NetCDF, with the output NetCDF containing the selected band(s) and the latitudes and longitudes.

The [data provider](https://nsidc.org/data/SPL3SMP_E/versions/4#sm) gives this info about the original file:

```
Table 2. Geolocation details for the Global EASE-Grid
Geographic coordinate system: WGS 84
Projected coordinate system: EASE-Grid 2.0 Global
Longitude of true origin: 0
Standard Parallel: 30° N
Scale factor at longitude of true origin: N/A
Datum: WGS 84
Ellipsoid/spheroid: WGS 84
Units: meter
False easting: 0
False northing: 0
EPSG code: 6933
PROJ4 string: +proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
Reference: http://epsg.io/6933

Table 3. Grid Details for the Global EASE-Grid
Grid cell size (x, y pixel dimensions): 9,024.31 m (x), 9,024.31 m (y)
Number of columns: 3,856
Number of rows: 1,624
Geolocated lower left point in grid: 85.044° S, 180.000 ° W
Nominal gridded resolution: 9 km by 9 km
Grid rotation: N/A
ulxmap – x-axis map coordinate of the outer edge of the upper-left pixel: -17367530.45 m
ulymap – y-axis map coordinate of the outer edge of the upper-left pixel: 7314540.83 m
```

When I do the conversion:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" infile.h5 outfile.nc
```

the latitudes and longitudes are in meters. For example (output from "ncdump -c outfile.nc"):

```
netcdf test {
dimensions:
        x = 3856 ;
        y = 1624 ;
variables:
        char lambert_cylindrical_equal_area ;
                lambert_cylindrical_equal_area:grid_mapping_name = "lambert_cylindrical_equal_area" ;
                lambert_cylindrical_equal_area:longitude_of_central_meridian = 0. ;
                lambert_cylindrical_equal_area:false_easting = 0. ;
                lambert_cylindrical_equal_area:false_northing = 0. ;
                lambert_cylindrical_equal_area:standard_parallel = 30. ;
                lambert_cylindrical_equal_area:long_name = "CRS definition" ;
                lambert_cylindrical_equal_area:longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0. ;
                lambert_cylindrical_equal_area:semi_major_axis = 6378137. ;
                lambert_cylindrical_equal_area:inverse_flattening = 298.257223563 ;
                lambert_cylindrical_equal_area:spatial_ref = "PROJCS[\"unnamed\",GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"unknown\",SPHEROID[\"WGS84\",6378137,298.257223563],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Cylindrical_Equal_Area\"],PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",30],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1]]" ;
        double x(x) ;
                x:standard_name = "projection_x_coordinate" ;
                x:long_name = "x coordinate of projection" ;
                x:units = "m" ;
        double y(y) ;
                y:standard_name = "projection_y_coordinate" ;
                y:long_name = "y coordinate of projection" ;
                y:units = "m" ;
        float Band1(y, x) ;
                Band1:long_name = "GDAL Band Number 1" ;
                Band1:_FillValue = 9.96921e+36f ;
                Band1:Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_PM_soil_moisture_pm_coordinates = "/Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_AM/latitude /Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_AM/longitude" ;
                Band1:Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_PM_soil_moisture_pm_long_name = "Representative SCA-V soil moisture measurement for the Earth based grid cell." ;
                Band1:Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_PM_soil_moisture_pm_units = "cm**3/cm**3" ;
                Band1:Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_PM_soil_moisture_pm_valid_max = "0.5 " ;
                Band1:Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_PM_soil_moisture_pm_valid_min = "0.02 " ;
                Band1:Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_PM_soil_moisture_pm__FillValue = "-9999 " ;
                Band1:grid_mapping = "lambert_cylindrical_equal_area" ;
data:

 x = 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 
    ...
    3851.5, 3852.5, 3853.5, 3854.5, 3855.5 ;

 y = 1623.5, 1622.5, 1621.5, 1620.5, 1619.5, 1618.5, 1617.5, 1616.5, 1615.5, 
     ...
    7.5, 6.5, 5.5, 4.5, 3.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0.5 ;
}
```

Can someone please show me how to get the output coordinates in degrees? i.e. just "ordinary" latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: EPSG:6933 has meters as unit http://epsg.io/6933. You must reproject your data into EPSG:4326 for getting degrees in WGS84.

Comment: `gdalwarp` for reprojecting.

Answer (score 2):

Following comments from @user2856 and @user30184 and info [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249841/parameters-of-projection-for-smap-data#comment392952_249841), the solution was:

```
gdal_translate -of NetCDF -a_nodata -9999 -a_ullr -17367530.45 7314540.83 17367530.45 -7314540.83 -a_srs "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" infile.h5 tmp.nc

gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:6933 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te_srs EPSG:4326 -of NetCDF tmp.nc outfile.nc
```