# SMAP projection

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, nasa, hdf5

I want to know how to convert the lat/lon fields in NASA's SMAP soil moisture data in HDF format to EPSG:4326.

Lat/lon fields in the SMAP HDF files contain 'Latitude/longitude of the center of a 9-km EASE 2.0 grid cell.', and **the EPSG:6933** according to [the official website](https://nsidc.org/data/spl3smp_e/versions/4/documentation). Therefore, I expected the projected coordinates to be fairly large values (-17357881 to 17357881/-7324184 to 7324184, units: meter) according to [EPSG.io](https://epsg.io/6933).

However, when I read the lat/lon data from SMAP website, and looked at the [official website Table A1](https://nsidc.org/data/spl3smp_e/versions/4/documentation), **the latitude/longitude value ranges only from -90 to +90/-180 to +180**.

**Does it mean the lat/lon values are already in EPSG4326? Or do I need to convert? If so, how?**

The followings are something that I tried:

(1) I referred to [this previous post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159883/how-to-define-a-projection-for-a-file-with-geo-points) but not sure this applies to SMAP too.

(2) I tried converting the EPSG4326 coordinates to EPSG6933, but it ended up in very large values between (-17357881 to 17357881/-7324184 to 7324184), and never matches with any SMAP lat/lon.

Here is how I read the lat/lon fields:

```
import h5py    
in_fn = "./1_data/SMAP/SMAP_L3_SM_P_E_20180701_R17000_001.h5
with h5py.File(in_fn, "r") as f:
        lat_am = np.array(f['Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_AM']['latitude'])
        lon_am = np.array(f['Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_AM']['longitude'])
```